# Where can a list of all existing HTML meta tags be found? (DUBLIN CORE, OPEN GRAPH etc)

Tags: html, schema, metadata, meta-tags

I am investigating the use and consumption of HTML meta tags.

Such as those defined by Dublin Core, Open Graph etc..

I am struggling to locate a definitive list of all possible meta tag schemas and for each schema a list of all possible tags.

for example where can I find a list of all possible meta tags that start "`citation_`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example where can I find a list of all possible meta tags that start "`citation_`"?

https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions lists about 20 "`citation_`" keywords.

> I am struggling to locate a definitive list of all possible meta tag schemas and for each schema a list of all possible tags.

There are currently 356 `meta` keywords listed on the wiki page cited above.

As far as how definitive that list is, [it’s the resource that the HTML spec itself cites](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#other-metadata-names):

> Also, before creating and using a new metadata name, consulting the WHATWG Wiki MetaExtensions page is encouraged — to avoid choosing a metadata name that's already in use, and to avoid duplicating the purpose of any metadata names that are already in use, and to avoid new standardized names clashing with your chosen name. [WHATWGWIKI]

Comment: I hadnt seen that wiki list before, however it only lists 26 citation_ tags and I have identified over 35 already! The search continues for a definitive source

Comment: If you’ve found more "`citation_`" keywords then I guess you should add them to that wiki page. I think there is otherwise no definitive list—because the thing is, there’s nothing to prevent anybody from just creating their own "`citation_`" keywords and using them without documenting them anywhere. Apparently that’s the case with the "`citation_`" keywords. It’s certainly the case with a lot of other meta keywords—that is, people use them without ever documenting them anywhere.

Comment: Thats what I was concerned about. I shall amend the wiki once I have completed my search/work